# How do I select all coplanar vertices?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm trying to use a Wireframe modifier on a Geodesic Dome shape made of hexagons. When I added the shape, it included vertices in the centers of all the hexagons, which don't show up in Object mode because they're coplanar with the surrounding vertices.

They are affecting the Wireframe modifier, though. How can I easily select them all so I can dissolve them?

[image: geodesic-dome-coplanar-vertices]

Comment: Did you try Shift+G menu? (and in this case Amount of Connected Edges) It won't select co-planar ones, rather than those selected on your screenshot

Comment: Yes, I did. Unfortunately, they _all_ have 6 surrounding edges of approximately equal length. Limited Dissolve turns out to do exactly what I was looking for, though.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can just use **Limited Dissolve** for this (removing them, not selecting them).

Comment: to make this answer more useful for others, if possible try to add some "solution" step, to explain what to do (keystrokes, menus), optionally an image of the result after using that command...